# How to simulate keypress events to change text content and submit a form in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, keyboard-events, inputsimulator

I want to create a JavaScript function that can simulate **keypress** events to change the text content inside a div and then submit it using a button click event.

For example, let's say I have a div with an ID of "`myDiv`", and I want to change its content to "Hello world!" and then submit it using a button with an ID of "`myButton`". How can I achieve this using JavaScript?

I want to simulate key press events and not directly change the text content using the `div.textContent` method. Specifically, I want to fill and submit a form where the text input is a div element with the `contenteditable` attribute set to `true`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
const tweetBox = document.querySelector("[data-testid='tweetTextarea_0']");
  tweetBox.focus();
  tweetBox.textContent = "";

  const text = "Hello, world!";
  for (const char of text) {
    const key = char.charCodeAt(0);
    console.log(key) ;
    const event = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", { keyCode: key });
    tweetBox.dispatchEvent(event);
  }

  const tweetButton = document.querySelector("[data-testid='tweetButtonInline']");
  tweetButton.click();

  console.log("\nButton Clicked");
```

The content inside of the div , is not being changed .

Comment: give me code HTML

Comment: You may find the link for the same here : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Sps-fkWWF7kLEMvFqOFTstHa3f7Y6OWR?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

If an event is created and dispatched, then `isTrusted` is set to `false`, whereas a user-initiated event sets `isTrusted` to `false`.

This means that the default event handler for keyboard events is not fired. However, the element still receives the event, and we can add out own event handler to provide similar functionality.

```
onkeydown='if (!event.isTrusted) this.textContent+=event.key;'
```

First determine whether the action is user-initiated or not, and alter the text manually if not (if you don't check `isTrusted`, user-typed text doubles up).

```js
function typeStr() {
  let str='hello world!';
  for (let ltr of str) {
    d=new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {key:ltr});
    out.dispatchEvent(d);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="out" style="border:black 2px solid" contenteditable
  onkeydown='if (!event.isTrusted) this.textContent+=event.key;'></div>
<button onclick="typeStr();">type</button>
```